# ASP.NET Load & Display DataGrid based on another control, when page loads

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, datagrid, event-handling

On my ASP.NET content page, I have a DropDownList and a DataGrid.  The DropDownList is populated from the results of an SQL query when the page loads.  I want the DataGrid to be populated from the results of an SQL Query, but that query depends on the selected item of the DropDownList.  I have an event handler for DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged, which calls a function `PopulateDG`.  This function gets the selected item from the DropDown (defaulting to the first element if SelectedItem is Nothing), creates an SQLDataAdapter, queries the database, fills the DataSet, and finally calls the DataGrid's `DataBind()`.  This all works perfectly when the function is called from the DropDown's event handler.

I would now like to have the DataGrid appear when the page is first loaded, using the information from the first element of the DropDown (since it'd be before the user has selected anything).  I have tried putting `PopulateDG` in the Init, PreInit, PreRender, Load, and Unload handlers for the Page and both controls, to no avail.  When I use the debugger, I can see that the ItemsGrid.DataSource does indeed have the information I want, but ItemsGrid.DataBind does not seem to cause the Data Grid to appear on the page like it does when called from the SelectedIndexChanged handler.  The control simply doesn't render onto the page.

PopulateDG:

```
Protected Sub PopulateDG()
    Dim WeekId As Integer
    Dim DDIdx As Integer
    If DropDownList1.SelectedItem Is Nothing Then
        DDIdx = 0
    Else
        DDIdx = DropDownList1.SelectedIndex
    End If
    WeekId = DropDownList1.Items.Item(DDIdx).Value

    Dim myConnection As SqlConnection
    Dim SQLCommand As SqlDataAdapter

    Dim rootWebConfig As System.Configuration.Configuration
    rootWebConfig = Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/Web.config")
    Dim connString As System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings
    connString = rootWebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString")
        If Not (connString.ConnectionString = Nothing) Then
            Console.WriteLine("Northwind connection string = " & connString.ConnectionString)
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("No Northwind connection string")
        End If

    myConnection = New SqlConnection(connString.ConnectionString)
    SQLCommand = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), WorkDate, 101) AS WorkDate, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), WorkStartTime, 8) AS StartTime, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), WorkEndTime, 8) AS EndTime, BreakMinutes FROM Days WHERE WeekId = " & WeekId & " ORDER BY WorkDate", myConnection)

    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
    SQLCommand.Fill(ds)
    ItemsGrid.DataSource = ds
    ItemsGrid.DataBind() 'DEBUGGER BREAK POINT HERE

End Sub
```

Content markup of my aspx page:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">

      <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1"
          runat="server" 
          DataSourceID="TimeSheetDB" 
          DataTextField="WeekEndLabel" 
          DataValueField="WeekId" 
          OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"
          AutoPostBack="True">
      </asp:DropDownList>
      <asp:SqlDataSource ID="TimeSheetDB" 
          runat="server" 
          ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
          SelectCommand="SELECT [WeekId], 'Week Ending ' + CONVERT(varchar(10), EndDate, 101) AS WeekEndLabel FROM [Weeks] ORDER BY [EndDate]">
      </asp:SqlDataSource>

      <asp:DataGrid id="ItemsGrid"
           BorderColor="black"
           BorderWidth="1"
           CellPadding="3"
           AutoGenerateColumns="true"
           runat="server"
           >
      </asp:DataGrid>

</asp:Content>
```

At the second to last line of the sub, I have a break point, and using the debugger I can see that ItemsGrid.DataSource.Tables.List(0) is populated exactly as I'd like, but the DataBind function seems to do nothing when called from anywhere except the SelectedItemChanged event handler.  How can I make it work correctly when the page first loads?

Comment: Paul L - the most helpful action if you have solved your own question is to add an answer and accept it.  This removes the question from the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: Ah, I see.  My apologies.  I will do that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. The call to PopulateDG has to come in the DropDown's PreRender event handler. My problem seems to have been that I was trying to use the function either too early (ie, before the items were loaded into the DropDown control) or too late (after ASP had already determined how the DataGrid should appear, I assume, so that calling DataBind at that point had no effect). Clearly, I need to read up more on the various execution phases of pages and controls.